# png texture with transparent background not properly blending with glass

Tags: texturing, transparency, glass

I’ve been working on this for the past few days and it’s almost ready. But I’ve noticed that when applying a transparent png texture over a glass material and alpha blending it, it is not quite looking good. There is a clear cut edge between the glass and the texture and it doesn’t look good when rendering it. By the way I'm using Cycles. I’ve attached a screenshot below.
[image]

[image]

here is my .blend file - https://pasteall.org/blend/9b226cf130ab456fbd355b21b16a6e93

Comment: Have you tried disabling "Show Backface"? Also, since the glass is "flat", you could probably get away with lowering the IOR slightly.

Comment: hello, it is hard to see what's happening, maybe pack the image and share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: You can't render multiple transparent objects behind each other with Eevee. This is one of the limitations of the engine.

Comment: @FFeller you can if you use alpha hashed.